# Get file extensions to populate into a ComboBox in C#

Tags: c#

So I have a folder with some imagens in many extensions like `.ico`, `.png`, `.jpg`, etc. and I've populated it into a `comboBox` using this code:

```
string caminho = @"C:\Users\User1\Desktop\Test\";
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(caminho);
FileInfo[] fi = dir.GetFiles();
foreach (var ficheiro in fi)
{
    string caminhoF = caminho + ficheiro.ToString();
    string extension = Path.GetExtension(caminhoF);
    comboBox1.Items.Add(extension);
}
```

The code is getting all the existing extensions in this path and put it on the `comboBox`, but it displays like this:

```
.ico
.ico
.ico
.png
.png
.jpg
.jpg
```

and I want to simply display each one of the existing extensions like grouping them.

Could you help me with that?

Comment: Do you mean distinct? And perhaps you want them sorted per the user's culture?

Comment: Yes basically using a `DISTINCT` like you use in SQL @TomBlodget

Answer (score 6):

You can get the file extension from the `FileInfo`. You can also use Linq `Distinct()` to get unique extensions.

```
string caminho = @"C:\Users\User1\Desktop\Test\";
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(caminho);
var extensions = dir.GetFiles().Select(fi => fi.Extension).Distinct();
foreach (var extension in extensions) {
    comboBox1.Items.Add(extension);
}
```

Comment: I like your answer because it is very performant and succinct.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I was to find a solution for it. Here it is the code:

```
string caminho = @"C:\Users\User1\Desktop\Test\";
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(caminho);
FileInfo[] fi = dir.GetFiles();
foreach (var ficheiro in fi)
{
    string caminhoF = caminho + ficheiro.ToString();
    string extension = Path.GetExtension(caminhoF);
    if (!comboBox1.Items.Contains(extension))
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Add(extension);
    }
}
```

Comment: The other answers may be better than this answer: repeatedly querying `Items.Contains()` may be slow.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the rough steps:

- Scan your folder to find out what files it contains.
- Extract the file extension from each file you find.
- Using a data structure that stores only unique entries, add extensions that you find to be new to the structure.
- Iterate over the data structure to populate your combobox.

The part that you need is to find a data structure that helps you store unique values.

[`HashSet<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353005(v=vs.110).aspx) has your back here: it allows quick lookups to determine set membership ("does the set already contain some element x?").

```
string caminho = @"C:\Users\User1\Desktop\Test\";
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(caminho);
FileInfo[] fi = dir.GetFiles();
HashSet<string> extensions = new HashSet<string>;

foreach (var ficheiro in fi)
{
    string caminhoF = caminho + ficheiro.ToString();
    string extension = Path.GetExtension(caminhoF);

    // If the set does not contain this extension, it'll be added and
    // `Add()` will return true. Otherwise, it will do nothing and `Add()`
    // will return false.
    extensions.Add( extension );
}

foreach( var extension in extensions ) {
    comboBox1.Items.Add(extension);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

LINQ-to-Objects makes this easy. LINQ is similar to SQL but allows chaining transformations.

```
var comboBox1 = new ComboBox();
var caminho = @"C:\Users\User1\Desktop\Test\";
var dir = new DirectoryInfo(caminho);
var extensions = dir.GetFiles()
       .Select(fi => fi.Extension)
       .OrderBy(ext => ext, StringComparer.CurrentCulture)
       .Distinct(StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
       .ToArray();
comboBox1.Items.AddRange(extensions);
```

Comment: Consider against calling `ToArray()` when not necessary - it incurs an unnecessary memory allocation. `Distinct()` already allocates and returns an `IEnumerable<T>`, might as well run a `foreach` loop over that instead. On the other hand, calling `Items.AddRange()` might be faster than a `foreach` calling `Items.Add()`..

Comment: @antiduh Considered. If one array allocation is going to a problem, having many thousands of items in a ComboBox list is going to be a bigger problem.